# Casting C++ pointer-to-member-variable to variable base type

Tags: c++, pointer-to-member

I have

```
class Base {}
class Derived : public Base {}

class Test {
Derived x;
}
```

I need to cast `&Test::x` from `Derived Test::*` to `Base Test::*`. I've tried `static_cast<Base Test::*>(&Text::x)` but it shows me an error.

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: If you state the objective of your code, maybe there is another way to do what you want.

Comment: @DevSolar Please read https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/pointer section "Pointers to members".

Comment: @anastaciu Maybe, but it should work this way anyway. Not being able to cast pointer to member variables to their base class types does not make sense.